# This is a computer graphics code for 2D rotation in TURBO C++. It compiles fine but I can't run it. What should I do?

Tags: turbo-c++, borland-c++, bgi

The code below compiles fine but I cant run it on TURBO C++. The runtime screen just flashes. But i have also used getch(). I dont know where I am going wrong. What should I do?

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<graphics.h>
void main()
{
    int gm;
    int gd = DETECT; //graphic driver
    int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, x1n, x2n, x3n, y1n, y2n, y3n, c; //vertices of triangle
    int r; //rotation angle  
    float t;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\TURBOC3:\BGI:");
    setcolor(RED);

    printf("\t Enter vertices of triangle: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &x1,&y1,&x2,&y2,&x3,&y3);
    line(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    line(x2,y2,x3,y3);
    line(x3,y3,x1,y1);

    printf("\nEnter angle of rotation: ");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    t = 3.14*r/180; //converting degree into radian
    
    //applying 2D rotation equations
    x1n = abs(x1*cos(t)-y1*sin(t));
    y1n = abs(x1*sin(t)+y1*cos(t));
    x2n = abs(x2*cos(t)-y2*sin(t));
    y2n = abs(x2*sin(t)+y2*cos(t));
    x3n = abs(x3*cos(t)-y3*sin(t));
    y3n = abs(x3*sin(t)+y3*cos(t));

    //Drawing the rotated triangle
    line(x1n,y1n,x2n,y2n);
    line(x2n,y2n,x3n,y3n);
    line(x3n,y3n,x1n,y1n);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the arguments to `initgraph` represent but, if the last is a directory+filename, then you'll need to escape the backslash (i.e. double it up).

Comment: haven't use BGI for decades so I might be wrong but are you sure you can use `printf` after initgraph? You know `printf` uses text mode (like cout) and BGI gfx mode maybe your print just resets  video mode back to mode 3  (80x25 text). The same goes for `scanf` ... Also you are runnung the Turbo C++under MS-DOS? DOSbox? differnet emulator? or you got entirely different compiler and use BGI port like winBGI under Win or Linux ? under DOS box you need more getch in series (at least 3) also try to hit IIRC [F5] to see what was outputed by your program.

Answer (score 0):

Many useful pieces of info in comments.

The problem (or at least the main one) is clear: path to *.bgi* files (*"C:\TURBOC3:\BGI:"*) is wrong, actually it's **not even a valid *Win* (*DOS*) path**.

- It contains a bunch of *colon*s (*:*), when only the drive letter (if present) should contain one
- It's always good to escape (double) *bkslash*es (*\*) in paths. This doesn't affect you in this case, but it's a general guideline

As a consequence, *initgraph* fails.

Another golden rule when programming, is: **always check a function outcome (return code, error flags, ...), don't assume everything just worked fine!** 
In this case, *graphresult* should be used. I don't know where the official documentation is (or if it exists), but here's a pretty good substitute: [[Colorado.CS]: Borland Graphics Interface (BGI) for Windows](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/bgi/doc/).

There are also some minor problems, like *printf* not functioning in graphic mode (*scanf* does, but it lets the user input to be displayed (in text mode), so it messes up (part of) the graphic screen).

Here's a modified version of the code (I added the *test* variable to avoid entering the 7 values every time the program is run).

*main00.c*:

```c
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    int err, gm, gd = DETECT;  // Graphic driver
    int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, x1n, x2n, x3n, y1n, y2n, y3n, c;  // Vertices of triangle
    int r;  // Rotation angle
    float t;
    int test = 1;  // Set to: 0 to read from keyboard, or anything else to use predefined values

    if (test) {
        x1 = 220;
        y1 = 200;
        x2 = 420;
        y2 = 200;
        x3 = 320;
        y3 = 280;
        r = 45;
    } else {
        printf("\nEnter vertices (x, y) of triangle: ");
        scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &x3, &y3);
        printf("\nEnter angle of rotation (degrees): ");
        scanf("%d", &r);
    }

    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "Y:\\BC\\BGI");  // You should use "C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI"
    err = graphresult();
    if (err != grOk) {
        printf("Error initializing graphics: %d\n", err);
        getch();
        return -1;
    }

    setcolor(WHITE);
    outtextxy(10, 10, "Triangle rotation demo");

    setcolor(LIGHTRED);
    line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    line(x2, y2, x3, y3);
    line(x3, y3, x1, y1);

    t = M_PI * r / 180;  // Converting degrees into radians
    // Applying 2D rotation equations
    x1n = abs(x1 * cos(t) - y1 * sin(t));
    y1n = abs(x1 * sin(t) + y1 * cos(t));
    x2n = abs(x2 * cos(t) - y2 * sin(t));
    y2n = abs(x2 * sin(t) + y2 * cos(t));
    x3n = abs(x3 * cos(t) - y3 * sin(t));
    y3n = abs(x3 * sin(t) + y3 * cos(t));

    // Drawing the rotated triangle
    setcolor(YELLOW);
    line(x1n, y1n, x2n, y2n);
    line(x2n, y2n, x3n, y3n);
    line(x3n, y3n, x1n, y1n);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (in a *DOSBox* emulator):

- Build:

  [image: Img00]
- Run:

  [image: Img01]

**Note**: The rotated triangle (yellow) might seem positioned a bit unexpectedly (translated), but that is because no rotation center is explicitly provided, so *O(0, 0)* (*origin* - upper left corner) is used, and the 3 points are rotated around it. 
If choosing one of the triangle vertices (or better: one of its centers) as rotation center, the 2 triangles will overlap, making the rotation more obvious. But that's just (plane) geometry, and it's beyond this question's scope.